# Removing Spotlight index for a no-more-existent Time Machine drive

Tags: finder, time-machine, spotlight

Suppose that an old full Time Machine drive is attached to a new macOS installation, and configured as the main backup storage (but no backup of the new position already begun). Spotlight started indexing the old drive, as usual.

How would I clear indexing data and related for this disk, if it has been successively erased (ExFAT) with Disk Utility?

Comment: Hi. What are you looking at to think an index is being preserved?

Comment: I don’t actually know if any index is preserved, just curious.

Answer (score 1):

Spotlight index for an external drive is stored on that drive, so you wiped it along with the data.